# Unable to generate tiles using gdal2tiles.py for a single band gray image

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, cesium, gdal2tiles

I am using and playing around with Cesium at the moment, and I am enjoying the functionality so far. I am trying to provide my own imagery to Cesium with the TMS imagery provider:

```
imageryProvider: new Cesium.createTileMapServiceImageryProvider({ 
  url: <my path>, 
  credit: "Some credit goes here..."
})
```

To create the tiles that I will need from a large tiff image, I am using the gdal command line utilities. Particularly, I am using gdalinfo, gdal_translate, gdalwarp and gdal2tiles.py. The image that I am starting off with is a tiff image with the following properties:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: pleiades_pan05m_2015-06-19.tif
Size is 52251, 56122
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 35S",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",27],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["meters",1],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32735"]]
Origin = (606275.000000000000000,7197875.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.500000000000000,-0.500000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE=4095
  TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE=1
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=ERDAS IMAGINE
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  606275.000, 7197875.000) ( 28d 3'21.55"E, 25d19'55.05"S)
Lower Left  (  606275.000, 7169814.000) ( 28d 3'29.52"E, 25d35' 7.16"S)
Upper Right (  632400.500, 7197875.000) ( 28d18'55.91"E, 25d19'47.53"S)
Lower Right (  632400.500, 7169814.000) ( 28d19' 5.83"E, 25d34'59.55"S)
Center      (  619337.750, 7183844.500) ( 28d11'13.20"E, 25d27'27.53"S)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Using gdal_translate, I first georeference the image by defining the ground control points, and choose an output format of VRT:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -gcp 606275 7197875 28.055987 -25.331974 -gcp 606275 7169814 28.058200 -25.585326 -gcp 632400.5 7197875 28.31553 -25.329876 -gcp 632400.5 7169814 28.318286 -25.583209 pleiades_pan05m_2015-06-19.tif output1.vrt
```

After this step, I warp the image. The original image wasn't created for a round globe, and a new projection (which Cesium requires) is necessary. My command I executed was:

```
gdalwarp -of VRT -t_srs EPSG:3857 output1.vrt output2.vrt
```

This warps the image to fit the globe in Cesium and creates a new output file which provides metadata about the warping procedure.

As a final step, I want to create the tiles. For this I used the python binding script gdal2tiles.py as follows:

```
gdal2tiles.py -v output2.vrt
```

The output for this command (using the verbose option) gave me the following output:

```
('Options:', <Values at 0x7f51a6c6eea8: {'profile': 'mercator', 'kml': False, 's_srs': None, 'copyright': '', 'resume': False, 'url': '', 'googlekey': 'INSERT_YOUR_KEY_HERE', 'bingkey': 'INSERT_YOUR_KEY_HERE', 'webviewer': 'all', 'zoom': None, 'resampling': 'average', 'tmscompatible': None, 'title': 'denel2.vrt', 'srcnodata': None, 'verbose': True}>)
('Input:', 'output2.vrt')
('Output:', 'output2')
Cache: 40 MB

('Input file:', '( 55470P x 54022L - 1 bands)')
NODATA: []
('Preprocessed file:', '( 55470P x 54022L - 1 bands)')
('Bounds (output srs):', 22.6588553403505, -90.3653010581841, 23.18345039115748, -89.8544001417483)
('Bounds (latlong):', (-0.000811765310920372, 0.00020354796072890105), (-0.0008071758099030093, 0.0002082604782500346))
('MinZoomLevel:', 26)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 2278, in <module>
    gdal2tiles.process()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 482, in process
    self.open_input()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 991, in open_input
    print("MaxZoomLevel:", self.tmaxz, "(", self.mercator.Resolution( self.tmaxz ),")")
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 286, in Resolution
    return self.initialResolution / (2**zoom)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

When I take away the verbose option, I get a similar error but at a different place:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 2278, in <module>
    gdal2tiles.process()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 485, in process
    self.generate_metadata()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 1135, in generate_metadata
    f.write( self.generate_tilemapresource())
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 1531, in generate_tilemapresource
    for z in range(self.tminz, self.tmaxz+1):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I am kind of stuck here at the moment, will anyone be able to help out here? Why (when I don't pass the verbose option), I get a NoneType error and why self.tmaxz is of type 'NoneType'? Am I missing something in my steps above?

Comment: you may want to provide some sample data to make it reproducible.

Comment: The original seems to be already georeferenced for EPSG:32735 so you do not need to write any ground control points. Gdal2tiles should work directly by using pleiades_pan05m_2015-06-19.tif as the source image.

Comment: @user30184 I need the file to be projected to EPSG:3857 for Cesium. Should I then leave out the gdal_translate step?

Comment: Gdal2tiles can do reprojection and the default profile is EPSG:3857 `-p PROFILE, –profile=PROFILE:
    Tile cutting profile (mercator,geodetic,raster) - default 'mercator' (Google Maps compatible)`.

Comment: Isn't the default profile EPSG:4326?

Comment: @dof1985 it is hard to provide you with the sample image that I am using (it is a few GB).

Comment: @user30184 after generating the tiles with gdal2tiles.py, I am getting (it seems) one zoom level with a lot of small tiles. Particularly I am getting level 18 it seems. How does it choose the zoom level as 18 if I haven't specified this? Does it use the coordinates and pixel values of the image to determine this? A sample of the images I am getting after running gdal2tiles.py can be seen here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B97NtaPJrVz-aVhoT0NzUVEyTjA

Comment: You can control the levels with -z. Script tries to create reasonable levels to suit with the native resolution and extent. Names of tile directories may show the levels which were created automatically. You can also open the gdal2tiles.py with text editor and read if there are useful comments.

Comment: I would trust the documentation about the default profile http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html